# Does our current notion of velocity/acceleration (based on calculus) require absolute time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, time

When people explain special relativity, they say that a velocity in one frame leads to time dilation in that frame relative to a stationary frame.

When we say something like $v=\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}t$ or $a=\mathrm{d}v/\mathrm{d}t$. Isn't dt something that cannot change? A smallest infinitesimal unchanging amount. Newton described it in terms of absolute space and time.

How does it make sense to define a velocity of one frame as $\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}t$ yet say that the rate of time itself changes?
Can $\mathrm{d}t$ change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Isn't dt something that cannot change?

In Special Relativity, time $t$ is a *coordinate* rather than a (universal) *parameter*.

To locate an *event* in spacetime in a particular reference frame, one must specify *4* coordinates, 3 spatial and 1 temporal.

So, a quantity like $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is a *coordinate velocity*; it is the rate of change of one coordinate with respect to another.

But coordinates are *not* absolute so, in Special Relativity, coordinate velocity and coordinate acceleration are *relative*, i.e., they depend on the coordinate system one chooses.

Now, the *worldline* of an object - the object's locus of events in spacetime - *is* absolute.  And, a *parameter* of the worldline is the *proper time* $\tau$, the time according to a clock stationary with respect to (carried along with) the object.

So, one can take the derivative of the coordinates of an object with respect to the proper time, e.g., $\frac{dx}{d\tau}$ where $d\tau$ is *invariant*, i.e., the same in all coordinate systems.

For example, the quantity $\frac{d\vec x}{d\tau}$ is called the *[proper velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_velocity)*, $\vec w$, of the object.

In addition, we have the change in *coordinate time* with respect to *proper time*, $\frac{dt}{d\tau} = \gamma$ where

$$\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}, v= |\frac{d\vec x}{dt}| $$

Thus, we have

$$\vec w = \frac{d\vec x}{d\tau} =  \frac{d\vec x}{dt}\frac{dt}{d\tau} = \gamma \vec v$$

Comment: Acceleration is absolute in special relativity. SR is formulated with respect to inertial reference frames, and acceleration is the same in all such frames.

Comment: @dgh, in SR, there is *coordinate acceleration* (the acceleration of an object in some reference frame which is necessarily frame dependent) and *proper acceleration* (the acceleration according to an accelerometer attached to the object) and these are *not* the same.  The meaning of the phrase "acceleration is absolute" means *the proper acceleration is absolute*, i.e., all observers agree on what the accelerometer attached to the object reads just as all observers agree on the elapsed time of a clock attached to the object, i.e., the *proper time*.

Comment: So special relativity is in some sense a reformulation of what we even mean by velocity?

Answer (score 1):

The operation that seems to be causing you confusion is called a boost. A boost is an operation on minkowski space-time that in many ways is analagous to a rotation in three dimensional space. So let's make sure we understand the analogous situation dealing with rotations in three dimensional space.

## Rotations

Let's imagine we have a stick which has a length $L$. Let's suppose we are in some coordinate system where the stick is in the $z$-$x$ plane, and it makes an angle $\theta$ with the $x$ axis. Then let's denote by $L_x$ the projection of its distance along the $x$-axis. Then $L_x = L \cos \theta$. Notice that you can also think of $\theta$ in terms of the relationship $\tan \theta = \frac{L_z}{L_x}$. This last form is similar to defining an (average) $x$-velocity to be $\frac{dx}{dt}$.

Now let's suppose we do a rotation by changing our axis so that the stick makes a smaller angle $\phi$ with the $x$-axis. We will find a very curious result: we find that $L_x$ has somehow gotten longer. Also if we look at $\frac{L_z}{L_x} = \tan \theta$, we find that it too has changed.

Now does this mean that we couldn't have defined $\theta$ in the first frame? No, of course we can define angles. It's just that the change when we change frames.

## Boosts

Now let's think about boosts. We have some space-time interval described by some $\Delta t$ and $\Delta x$. There is an average velocity $v=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$. This is no harder to define than an angle in space.

Now suppose we do a boost. This looks similar to a rotation and $\Delta t$ and $\Delta x$ will both change, and their quotient $v=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$ will also change. But this is fine. It is just like how our $\theta$ changed when we did a rotation.

So to answer your question, yes it does make sense to define velocities in minkowski space, just as much as it makes sense to define angles in euclidean space. And yes $\mathrm{d} t$ does change when you do a boost, but that is expected, and consistent with the fact that the speed changes.